# Need a good colocation host

Tags: hosting, colocation

I'm looking for a good collocation host in Los Angeles.  I've looked at quite a few hosts, but found precious few reviews.  Has anyone had particularly good or bad experiences that can point me in a good direction?

We will be starting out with 2U's and I'm leaning towards burstable bandwidth rather than 95th percentile.

Thanks for the ideas.

Comment: Can't say specifically for LA but I've always used [webhostingtalk](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/) to search for service providers.

Answer (score 1):

Equinix is where it's at. But you'll be renting cages from them, not individual racks or rack units. A small cage (I think the smallest they can give you is enough for 5 racks) should set you back anywhere between $10k to $20k per month, depending on your negotiating position. You arrange your own bandwidth on top of that from one of the zillion NSPs they have inhouse.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

http://deru.com Or  hostdime.com

Comment: do you have any experience with these companies? they look rather small or unfocused on colocation.